# Contact form submission that send email and records data in csv

Tags: php, forms, csv, contacts

I have a contact form that on submit displays a thank you message, takes the users entries and emails them to an address but should also take four fields and place it into a CSV. Unfortunately I can't get the last part to work no matter what I try.

The thank you message works, an email is sent, but the part I've added at `$output` (before the if/else) doesn't.

Here's the code I'm using, thanks in advance to anyone who can help with this.

```
<?php

$subject = 'Submission received'; 
$mailto  = ''; 

$firstName      = $_POST['firstName'];
$lastName       = $_POST['lastName'];
$email          = $_POST['email'];
$telephone      = $_POST['telephone'];
$company        = $_POST['companyName'];
$country        = $_POST['country'];
$about          = $_POST['hearAbout'];
$enquiry        = $_POST['enquiry'];

$body = "
<br>
<p>The following information was submitted through the contact form on your website:</p>
<p><b>Name</b>: $firstName $lastName<br>
<b>Email</b>: $email<br>
<b>Phone number</b>: $telephone</br>
<b>Company name</b>: $company<br>
<b>Country</b>: $country<br>
<b>Heard about company via</b>: $about<br>
<b>Enquiry</b>: $enquiry<br></p>
";

// Success Message - PAD THIS OUT
$success = "
<div class=\"\">
    <div class=\"\">
        <h3>Submission successful</h3>
        <p>Thank you.</p> 
    </div>
</div>
";

$headers = "From: $firstName $lastName <$email> \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
$headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n";
$message = "<html><body>$body</body></html>";

$output = $firstName . "t";
$output .= $lastName . "t";
$output .= $email . "t";
$output .= $telephone . "n";
$fp = fopen("data/enquiry.csv", "a");
fwrite($fp, $output);
fclose($fp);

if (mail($mailto, $subject, $message, $headers)) {
        echo "$success"; // success
} else {
    echo 'Form submission failed. Please try again...'; // failure
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will help:

```
$fp = fopen("data/enquiry.csv", "a");
fwrite($fp,"," . $firstName . "," . $lastName . "," . $email . "," . $telephone . "\n");
fclose($fp);
```

Comment: Thank you - worked a charm! Seems like it didn't like not being in an array.